# Group by inside inner join 1055

Tags: mysql, sql, database, error-handling, sql-order-by

So, i have 2 tables one of them is a control list of holidays (1 for holiday and 0 for not holiday) and the day of the week on that date it kinda looks like this:

| calendar_date | Day_of_week | Holiday_flg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-02 | Monday | 1 |
| 2016-02-03 | Friday | 0 |
| 2016-02-01 | Monday | 1 |

And a second table with some restaurant info that looks like this:

Visit date: refers to the day the visitors arrive at the restaurant

Reserve visitors: refers to the day the visitors created a reservation on the restaurant (not used in this problem, just part of the main table)

| ID | Visit_date | reserve_datetime | reserve_visitors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1023044 | 2016-02-01 | 2016-01-01 | 5 |
| 1041331 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-01 | 2 |
| 1023044 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-01 | 4 |

I used this query to join both tables together by date

```sql
SELECT  * from restaurants_visitors 
inner join date_info
on restaurants_visitors.visit_date= date_info.calendar_date
where holiday_flg=1 
limit 10
;
```

which returns both tables joined by the date

I want to group them by restaurant ID, so i can get the highest average number of vistors on holidays, and the percentage of growth of the amount of visitors week over week for the last 4 weeks

So far i have tried something like this

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants_visitors as rv 
inner join date_info as df
on rv.visit_date= df.calendar_date
where df.holiday_flg=1
group by rv.id
limit 10
;
```

But i keep getting this error code:

**Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.restaurants_visitors.visit_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by    0.024 sec**

**Expected Output**

- List of top 5 more visited restaurants in holidays( Table with id of restaurant and avg visitors on holidays)in dsc order

| ID | Average_visitorsin_holidays |
| --- | --- |
| 1023044 | 4.5 |
| 1041331 | 2 |

- List of percentage of growth of the amount of visitors week over week for the last four weeks of the data?(Table with percentage of growth over weeks)

| week | percentage of growth over last week |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | unknow result |
| 3 | unknow result |

- Which day of the week there are usually more visitors on average in restaurants.
  (single row with day of the week with more visitors)

| Day of the week | AVG visitor per day of week |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 4.5 |
| 1041331 | 1 |

Comment: Your second snippet is identical to the first one, are you sure it's correct? @SovietCoder

Comment: @lemon thank you, I just edited the first snippet

Comment: @SovietCoder the last query doesn't have the GROUP BY that is causing the error

Comment: @Kurt it was another typo i just updated that snippet as well

Comment: @JonArmstrong what does the SELECT rv.id, COUNT(*) in this example?

Comment: @JonArmstrong each restaurant has an average of visitors in the holidays

let's say restaurant "a" has an average of 3 visitors in holidays
while restaurant "b", has an average of 5 visitors in holidays

I'm looking to get the 5 restaurants with the avg visitors in holidays

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the main problem is that you're selecting ALL the columns but only defining rv.id as the group identifier.

You want to start with something like this:

```
SELECT 
    rv.id, 
    df.calendar_date, 
    sum(rv.reserve_visitors) as total_visitors
FROM 
    restaurants_visitors as rv 
    inner join 
    date_info as df on rv.visit_date= df.calendar_date
WHERE 
    df.holiday_flg=1
GROUP BY 
    rv.id, 
    df.calendar_date
```

This will tell you the total visitors per restaurant per holiday.  With that in hand, we can find the average visitors per restaurant on holidays:

```
WITH
    holiday_visitors as (
        SELECT 
            rv.id, 
            df.calendar_date, 
            sum(rv.reserve_visitors) as total_visitors
        FROM 
            restaurants_visitors as rv 
            inner join 
            date_info as df on rv.visit_date= df.calendar_date
        WHERE 
            df.holiday_flg=1
        GROUP BY 
            rv.id, 
            df.calendar_date
    )
SELECT
    id,
    avg(total_visitors) as avg_holiday_visitors
FROM
    holiday_visitors
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    avg_holiday_visitors desc
```

This will tell you which restaurants had the most traffic on average on holidays.  How you limit it to the top 5 depends on the database you are using.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks, but now how do I get the highest average number of visitors on holidays?, btw i didnt know it was possible to group by several types

Comment: that depends on how you define the average.  now that you have the total visitors per restaurant per holiday, you could wrap this query in an outer query that calculates the avg per holiday, or the average per restaurant, whichever is appropriate.  Then just order that query DESC by avg_visitors

Comment: I'm looking to calculate the average per restaurant, could you please show me how?, I'm kinda new to SQL, also if you could help me with the other cases would be awesome thanks in advance